# Dask client using a remote interpreter

Tags: python, dask

I'm trying to use dask from Pycharm using a remote (SSH) interpreter.

Here's some code:

```
from dask.distributed import Client
client = Client(processes=True)
```

On Python 2 this seems to work fine, but on Python 3 this fails with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/forkserver.py", line 278, in main
    code = _serve_one(child_r, fds,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/forkserver.py", line 317, in _serve_one
    code = spawn._main(child_r, parent_sentinel)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 125, in _main
    prepare(preparation_data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 236, in prepare
    _fixup_main_from_path(data['init_main_from_path'])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 287, in _fixup_main_from_path
    main_content = runpy.run_path(main_path,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 261, in run_path
    code, fname = _get_code_from_file(run_name, path_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 231, in _get_code_from_file
    with open(fname, "rb") as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/ubuntu/<input>'
distributed.nanny - WARNING - Restarting worker
```

/home/ubuntu exists and is writable- I'm not sure what /home/ubuntu/input is though!

Does anyone have an idea as to what is going wrong here?

**EDIT**
so after a bit of tracing back I can see that in multiprocess/spawn.py on line 226, there is a prepare function which takes a map of properties describing the processed to be spawned.  For some reason the 'init_main_from_path' in that map is  being set to `/home/ubuntu/<input>` which is a directory that doesn't exist anywhere (I'm not even usre this is a valid directory name!).  It looks like the PyCharm console is setting this to help itself with the remote execution, but it's messing up the ability of multiprocess to correctly spawn a process.  If I hack multiprocess/spawn.py to remove the rogue 'init_main_from_path' key then I can start the client.

Comment: which version of dask are you using? are you sure it's compatible with python3? I just tested this code with dask 2.8.0 and it worked fine

Comment: It's dask 2.8.0.  I think the problem is specific to the remote interpreter because if I just log on to the machine and stat up a python3 shell I can execute the above code just fine.

Comment: hmm when you say the dir exists and is writable, does it exist on your local machine? on the remote machine? not sure on which one it should be (i think local because this is where you're running the code), but maybe worth checking

Comment: It exists on the remote machine- which is where I'm running the code.  I've traced the problem back to where multiprocess tries to spawn a new process.  Let me update the question.

Comment: I see the edit. You can also map local to remote directories in the edit run configuration... of Pycharm.